# unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Tags: php

Full path to working directory.
Makes it possible to for example to have effective exclude path in apc.
**DIR** breaks symlinked includes, but realpath() returns false
if we don't have permissions on parent directories.

```
$IP = getenv( 'MW_INSTALL_PATH' );
if ( $IP === false ) {
    if( realpath( '.' ) ) {
        $IP = realpath( '.' );
    } else {
        $IP = dirname( __DIR__ );
    }
}

if ( $IP === false ) {
    if( realpath( '.' ) ) {
        $IP = realpath( '.' );
    } else {
        $dirnamefile = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\w\";
        $IP = dirname( $dirnamefile );
    }
}
```

The code in second box was modified by me and the code above this is a default wiki code(mediawiki)

when I try to execute this I get this error
`Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\w\includes\WebStart.php on line 104`

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Which one is line 104?

Answer (score 3):

You're escaping the last quotation mark of your string, so the string doesn't terminate:

```
$dirnamefile = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\...\w\";
                                                                       ^^
```

Change it to:

```
$dirnamefile = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\...\w\\";
```

Note the added `\`.